# Getting checked input values in a specific div - simple jquery question

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

Here is my *div* that is contained more than once by my page:

```
<div class="formContainerDiv" style="width:165px">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                Assign To<br />
                <asp:CheckBoxList ID="CheckBoxListLoginUsers" runat="server">
                </asp:CheckBoxList>
                <br />
                Note<br />
                <asp:TextBox ID="TextBoxNote" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="150" ClientIDMode="Static" class="textBoxNote"></asp:TextBox>
                <br />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="button" class="saveAssignment" value="Save"/>
            </td>
            <td style="text-align: center;">
                <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="formContainerDivClose">Close</a>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

And that's my jquery function:

```
$(".saveAssignment").click(function () {
    var div = $(this).parents(".formContainerDiv");
    ......
});
```

I can select the appropriate *formContainerDiv*. But I need to get the values of checked checkboxes and the value of *TextBoxNote*.

How can I do that?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use the `closest` instead of `parents`, as you have multiple `.formContainerDiv`

Second, after finding `.formContainerDiv` with `$(div.find("input:textbox")[0]).val()` and `$(div.find("input:checkbox:checked")[0]).val()` locate the desired

Answer (score 1):

To loop through all the checked checkboxes in CheckBoxListLoginUsers:

```
    $.each($("#CheckBoxListLoginUsers :checked"), function(){
     //value of the checkbox is $(this).val();
    });
```

To get the value of TextBoxNote:

```
$("#TextBoxNote").val();
```

Comment: You have given the wrong second piece of advice. if .formContainerDiv contained in server component, found nothing, because asp.net will change id